# How to unit test Object.defineProperty on window object with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

Say I have the following (simplified) JavaScript code in script.js

```
(function() {
  var _val;
  Object.defineProperty(window, "myCallback", {

    // ...

    set: function(val) {
      _val = val;
      setTimeout(_val, 0);
    }
  });
})();
```

Now I'm trying to create a spec which asserts that the passed val callback gets called.

The following (simplified) scriptSpec.js:

```
describe("setter", function() {

  var spy = jasmine.createSpy('callback');

  it("should call passed callback", function() {
     window.myCallback = spy;
     expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

This spec has a problem, in that it does not register my property on the window object, therefore, the call to

> window.myCallback

in my test, does not call the setter.

Is there any reasonable approach for testing such things with Jasmine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was setting the _*val* variable from within a *setTimeout()* function call. Jasmine's expect would then be called before *setTimeout()* managed to do its job.

I were able to verify the setter behavior by using the *runs / waits* feature of Jasmine.

```
it("should call passed callback", function() {
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy('callback');
    runs(function () { window.myCallback = spy; });
    waits(10);
    runs(function () { expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple mistake. You're not using your spy in your test case.

```
describe("setter", function () {
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy("callback");  // "callback" is just the internal name

    it("should call passed callback", function () {
        window.myCallback = spy;  // <--- Use the actual spy object here
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for noting that (updated the sample). This however was only a typo when simplifying my more complex js code.

Comment: Strange. When I ran your sample code with my fix, the spy was called and the expectation passed. Have you tried writing your setter to accept an object instead of hard-coding `window`?

Comment: Forgive my inadvertence. The property setter in my production code had in fact been wrapped in a setTimeout() function call (see my own answer for details on how I fixed the unit test).